# Change the Bone Rotation (Quaternions) of an Armature in text script

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones

I am using Blender 2.49b. I have a hand model and I would like to set the bone rotation (in quaternions) to take values from text (Bone%i.txt); on each column of the text I have 4 values (W,X,Y,Z). My hand model consists of 25 bones, as can be seen in the following image.

[image]

So, I wrote the following script to do the job

```
from Blender import *
import math

# Path to data directory
dataDirectory = 'C:/Users/andarist/Desktop/Data'

# Number of frames to render
numFrames = 100

# Range of bones
handIndices = range(1,26)

# Bone file name patterns
bonePattern = 'Bone%i.txt'

# Hand object pattern
handObjectPattern = 'Bone.%03i'

# Global scale
scale = 1.0

# Global speed
speed = 1

def FrameChange():
    pass

def SetIpoForFrame(frame):
    frameIdx = (Get('curframe') - 1) * speed
    Set('curframe', frame)
    frameIdx = (frame - 1) * speed
    dataStore = Registry.GetKey('MoCapImporter')
    nanmap = { }

    # Move bones
    for handIdx in handIndices:
        handObj = Object.Get(handObjectPattern % handIdx)
        pos = dataStore['Bone'][handIdx-1][frameIdx]
        nanmap[handObjectPattern % handIdx] = False
        if(pos == None):
            nanmap[handObjectPattern % handIdx] = True
            pos = nanpos
        handObj.setRotation(scale*pos[0], scale*pos[1], scale*pos[2], scale*pos[3])
        handObj.insertIpoKey(Object.IpoKeyTypes.LOCROTSIZE)

    Scene.GetCurrent().update()

def LoadFile(pattern, index):
    fileName = dataDirectory + '/' + (pattern % index)
    file = open(fileName)
    lines = file.readlines()
    output = []
    for line in lines:
        c = line.split()
        if(c[1] == 'NaN'):
            output.append(None)
        else:
            output.append((float(c[0]), float(c[1]), float(c[2]), float(c[3])))
    file.close()
    print "Read %i lines from %s" % (len(output), fileName)
    return output

def Main():
    dataStore = { 'Bone': [] }
    # Attempt to load the data
    for handIdx in handIndices:
        data = LoadFile(bonePattern, handIdx)
        dataStore['Bone'].append(data)
    Registry.SetKey('MoCapImporter', dataStore, False)  

    for i in range(1, numFrames+1):
        print "Frame %i/%i" % (i, numFrames)
        SetIpoForFrame(i)


if((event == 'FrameChanged') or (event == 'Render')):
    FrameChange()
elif(event == ''):
    Main()
```

However, it seems that the `Object.Get` function cannot find the bone.%3i from Armatures hand, and I get the following error

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help and consideration.

Best Wishes,

Andreas

Comment: 2.49 .. From memory `Blender.Object.Get(handObjectPattern % handIdx)` returns a blender object, whereas you want to get a bone from the hand objects pose bone collection.  Is there a getPose() and or PoseBoneDictionary()...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find such a function as getPose() or PoseBoneDictionary().

Comment: Do you really need to stay with the 6 year old version of blender? Have you tried opening your models in a recent version? You will get more python help if you are using a more recent version.

Comment: getPose example on the Pose module page  https://www.blender.org/api/249PythonDoc/Pose-module.html, in particular `pose = arm_ob.getPose()`  `pbones = pose.bones.values()`  Agree with @sambler if you are unfamiliar with 2.49 API why not start afresh and open in recent version.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. It is true that it is much easier in later versions of Blender (e.g.v2.76). The solution to the problem is given at this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48488/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. The answer is given by Mutant Bob on a different threat: [Set the Rotation (in Quaternion WXZY) of a bone using API 2.49](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48488/)

```
    arm_ob = scn.objects.active
    bones = arm_ob.pose.bones

    for handIdx in handIndices:
        print(handIdx)
        pos = dataStore['Bone'][handIdx - 1][frameIdx]
        bone = bones[handIdx - 1]
        bone.rotation_quaternion = pos
        arm_ob.keyframe_insert(data_path = ("pose.bones[\"%s\"].rotation_quaternion"%bone.name ) )
        #bone.insertIpoKey(Object.IpoKeyTypes.LOCROTSIZE)

    scn.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be hard finding someone that remembers how to use python in 2.49. The 2.49 [api docs are still available here](https://www.blender.org/api/249PythonDoc/).

The second example on the [armature page](https://www.blender.org/api/249PythonDoc/Armature-module.html) might be what you are looking for - while the docs list `Get()` as a function the example uses `arm_ob.getData()`

```
scn= Scene.GetCurrent()
arm_ob= scn.objects.active
arm_data= arm_ob.getData()
bones= arm_data.bones.values()

for bone in bones:
    # use bone here
```